# Get count of count of unique values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get counts of unique counts of unique values for a column in pandas dataframe.

Sample data bellow:

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3], [5, 1]], columns=['AppointmentId', 'PatientId'])

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   AppointmentId  PatientId
0              1          1
1              2          1
2              3          2
3              4          3
4              5          1
```

Actual dataset has over 50000 unique values of `PatientId`. I want to visualize appointment count per patient, but simply grouping by `PatientId` and getting sizes of groups doesn't work well for plotting, because that would be 50000 bars.

For that reason I'm trying to plot how many patients had a specific number of appointments plotted, instead of plotting number of appointments against `PatientId`.

Based on sample data above I want to get something like this:

```
   AppointmentCount  PatientCount
0                 1             2
1                 3             3
```

I approach this by first grouping on `PatientId` and getting group sizes, drop `PatientId`, and group sizes, but I can't find a way to extract it after grouping.

```
In [24]: appointment_counts = df.groupby('PatientId').size()

In [25]: appointment_counts
Out[25]:
PatientId
1    3
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64

In [26]: type(appointment_counts)
Out[26]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `groupby` adding `value_counts`

```
df.groupby('PatientId').size().value_counts()
Out[877]: 
1    2
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Then you can add `rename`

```
df.groupby('PatientId').size().value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Aid',0:'Pid'})
Out[883]: 
   Aid  Pid
0    1    2
1    3    1
```

Comment: @JustinasMarozas yw:-)